How to upload a csv Emails file to Sendgrid Verification?
Here is the code to init the PUT of a CSV file to verify validity of emails listed in this CSV :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SendGrid;

public class Program {
    public static async Task Main() {

        string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var data = @"{
            ""file_type"": ""csv""
        }";

        var response = await client.RequestAsync(
            method: SendGridClient.Method.PUT,
            urlPath: "validations/email/jobs",
            requestBody: data
        );

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
    }
}

How to post a local EMails.csv in this C# function ?
In CURL we can do that :
curl -X PUT "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/validations/email/jobs" 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" 
--data '{"file_type": "csv"}'
curl --upload-file "./path/to/your/EMails.csv"
"https://example.com/the-unique-url-from-the-put-request" \ -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms"
-H "content-type: text/csv"
I have no idea how to translate the second part in C# in my Main function.
Thanks in advance for help

Open the CSV file using a CSV file reader class (check available libraries to do that) into a buffer (byte array). And then pass that byte array in the request body.
